# can't import six.moves module

Tags: python, django, disqus

```
import json

from six.moves.urllib_parse import urlencode
from six.moves.urllib_request import urlopen
from django.core.management.base import CommandError


def call(method, data, post=False):
    """
    Calls `method` from the DISQUS API with data either in POST or GET.
    Returns deserialized JSON response.
    """
    url = "%s%s" % ("http://disqus.com/api/", method)
    if post:
        # POST request
        url += "/"
        data = urlencode(data)
    else:
        # GET request
        url += "?%s" % urlencode(data)
        data = ""
    res = json.load(urlopen(url, data))
    if not res["succeeded"]:
        raise CommandError(
            "'%s' failed: %s\nData: %s" % (method, res["code"], data)
        )
    return res["message"]
```

> module) moves
> Import "six.moves.urllib_parse" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource

installed the six module
to Python virtual environment

six can be imported without problems,
Occurs from six.moves MissingModuleSource

Why can't Import? six.moves

Answer (score 0):

try changing system interpreter path of python in your IDE and set it to the virtual environment you use, in which you have installed the module.

[an example in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1nXC.png)

Comment: I am using the virtual environment interpreter

Normally import six so it's not an interpreter problem

MissingModuleSource error occurs from six.moves